# Getting NOT IN subset with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a SQL/Postgres database where I keep the application data, including references to user-generated content persisted in object storage - image files. Every now and then, these user-generated files get overwritten or deleted. I would like to add garbage collection to clean up the unused storage.

My plan is:

1. get a list of files from the object store.
2. randomly select a subset of maybe 100 files at a time.
3. use FaaS to run something like the below query every few minutes:

```
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      events e, categories c
    WHERE
      e.image <> ANY($1) AND
      e.cropped_image <> ANY($1) AND
      e.cropped_image_thumb <> ANY($1) AND
      e.promoted_img <> ANY($1) AND
      c.header_image <> ANY($1) AND
      c.list_image <> ANY($1)
```

Only, the query is working "backwards" - incorrectly. My version will return a list database records not containing the images. I want a list of images no longer referenced in the database.

Can I somehow join on the array `$1` and get elements not matching anything?

Comment: Perhaps `= ALL` vulgo `IN`?

Comment: `<> ALL (...)` corresponds to `NOT IN `

Comment: I don't understand why you are cross joining the two tables to start with. And for the last 30 years approximately, we have been using explicit joins instead of old 1980s comma joins. So, if you want a cross join, then write `FROM events e CROSS JOIN categories c`.

Comment: And $1 contains a string holding an image name or path? You don't have an image table with one row per image file and an ID that you'd reference in  the other places?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner `$1` of course holds an array of values, hence the post says: `join on the array $1`

Comment: @ThorstenKettner about implicit joins vs explicit, it is a great discussion. I value your opinion as to which ones are better, but my aim is actually something else.

Comment: Okay, I think a_horse_with_no_name has given you the answer you are looking for. `image <> ANY($1)` is true when we find an elemant in $1 that doesn't match (which is always the case, because it can't possibly match all elements at the same time unless $1 only contains one element). You need `image <> ALL($1)`, because you want image to mismatch all entries.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i think that you do not understand what i need. do appreciate you trying to help. however, you did not understand the question, i think. `ALL` or `ANY`, will return values from the database.